# How To Customize a Theme in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, themes

phpMyAdmin provides instructions for creating a custom theme.  I am wondering if there is a step I am missing.

The instructions are:

- make a new subdirectory (for example “your_theme_name”) under ./themes/.
- copy the files and directories from pmahomme to “your_theme_name”
- edit the css-files in “your_theme_name/css”
- put your new images in “your_theme_name/img”
- edit _variables.scss in “your_theme_name/scss”
- edit theme.json in “your_theme_name” to contain theme metadata (see below)
- make a new screenshot of your theme and save it under “your_theme_name/screen.png”

The css-files in “your_theme_name/css” appear minified. That leads me to expect those files are generated, using other files as inputs to generate them.  Is that right?  It really necessary to directy edit the minified css files?

Comment: Probably we forgot to update the directions, mostly the CSS is generated from SCSS files now. Are you referencing "Creating a custom theme" section of the documentation (which appears at https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/themes.html or in your own local phpMyAdmin documentation)? I'll make a ticket for us to update the documentation.